# MySQL com NodeJS: inserção de registros

Tags: mysql, node.js

Criei um script chamado 'teste.js" apenas para demonstrar uma inserção simples de registros de log num banco de dados MySQL, usando NodeJS, conforme segue abaixo. Serão gerados algo em torno de 5 logs por segundo, o que me faz supor que vai exigir um certo processamento da máquina para ficar executando este meu script a cada log gerado. 
Minha dúvida é: existe uma maneira de deixar uma conexão aberta para que os registros de log vão sendo inseridos, sem a necessidade de ficar abrindo e fechando a conexão a cada log? Ou sei lá... se existir uma maneira mais adequada totalmente diferente, gostaria de conhecer qualquer alternativa.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '123456',
    database: 'meu_db_teste'
});

con.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log('Erro de conexão do DB');
        return;
    }
    console.log('Conexão estabilizada com threadId: ', con.threadId);
});

// Estes dados do "reg_log" virão de um outro script
const reg_log = { info: 'abcde...xyz', dttime: 'xx:xx:xx' };
con.query('INSERT INTO logs SET ?', reg_log, (err, res, fields) => {
    if(err) throw err;

    console.log('Last insert ID:', res.insertId);
});

con.end((err) => {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

O cenário ideal é separar o arquivo de conexão com banco para implementar algum tipo de *singleton*, algo assim:

**connection.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
var single_connection;
module.exports = function() {
    if (!single_connection) {
        single_connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: '123456',
            database: 'meu_db_teste'
        });
    }
    return single_connection;
}
```

**teste.js**

```
const db = require('connection);
...
```

Comment: Lucas, grato pelo retorno, para mim está clara a intenção ao separar a parte da conexão em um arquivo independente, mas só para entender: vou ter um script meu, que vai ficar monitorando uma determinada condição do sistema. A cada vez que essa condição for verdadeira, eu chamo meu script para criar um registro no banco de dados e, neste meu script haverá o seu `const db = require('connection);`, ok! Isso não é a mesma coisa que eu estou fazendo lá no meu exemplo, só que no meu exemplo é sem arquivos separados?

Comment: Na verdade não, `require` é singleton e a diferença é que se já houver uma conexão com o banco, se só irá retornar ela quando os arquivos forem corridos.

Comment: e neste caso não é necessário encerrar a conexão? Pois suponho que vai dar timeout essa conexão aberta por muito tempo... Se sim, em que momento eu vou encerrar?

Comment: A conexão eu geralmente deixo uma aberta durante o ciclo de vida da aplicação @wBB, e gerencio o pull de conexões

Comment: Ok. Vou tentar aqui para ver o que acontece. Ainda falta implementar uma parte para rodar um teste mais próximo da situação real. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

arquivo dbconnection:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connMysql = () => {
    return mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '1234',
        database: 'banco'
    });
}

module.exports = () => {
    console.log('Conexao estabelecida com banco de dados');
    return connMysql;
}
```

usando models:

```
function NoticiasDao(connection) {
    this._connection = connection;
}


NoticiasDao.prototype.getNoticias =  function(callback){
    this._connection.query('select * from noticias', callback);
}


NoticiasDao.prototype.getNoticia = function(callback) {
    this._connection.query('select * from noticias where idNoticias = 2', callback);
}


NoticiasDao.prototype.salvarNoticia = function(noticia, callback) {
    this._connection.query('insert into noticias set ?', noticia, callback);
}



module.exports = function() {

    return NoticiasDao;
}
```

Controller :

```
module.exports.formulario = function(app, req, res) {
    response.render("admin/form_add_noticia", { validation: '',noticia:noticia});
}

module.exports.salvarNoticia = function(app, req, res) {
    var noticia = request.body;
    var connection = app.config.dbconnection();
    var noticiaDao = new app.app.models.NoticiasDao(connection);


            noticiaDao.salvarNoticia(noticia, function(error, result) {
                response.redirect('/noticias');
            });

    });
}
```

usando consign você inicializa conexao , models, controller ao iniciar server

```
var consign = require('consign');
consign()
    .include('app/routes')
    .then('config/dbconnection.js')
    .then('app/models')
    .then('app/controllers')
    .into(app);
```

Comment: Eduardo, grato pelo retorno, mas sou iniciante em NodeJs e estou me debatendo para entender como as coisas realmente funcionam. Não sei nem como usar seu exemplo e gostaria de entender como esse modo de inserir os registros diminuem o processamento da máquina.